# Continuous linear operator T at a point T is then continued

Tags: functional-analysis

The problem is the next If T is continuous at a single point, it is continuous, without using that T is continuous iff T is  bounded.

I tried this result as follows

If T is continuous at a single point $x_0$ implies T is continuous at $0$ then, it proves that if T is continuous at zero then T is continuous.

T continuous at zero $\Rightarrow \forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0 \text{ s.t }||x||<\delta\Rightarrow ||T(x)||<\epsilon$.

After, assume $x=y-x_0,\forall x_0\in X$, then $||y-x_0||<\delta\Rightarrow ||T(y)-T(x_0)||<\epsilon$.

Therefore we have that T is continuous $\forall x_0 \in X$.

My proof is correct ?

Comment: I think your proof if correct! Also, we have since $\left\vert \frac{\delta}{2}\frac{x}{\left\vert x\right\vert }\right\vert
<\delta\rightarrow T\left(  \frac{\delta}{2}\frac{x}{\left\vert x\right\vert
}\right)  <\varepsilon\rightarrow T\left(  x\right)  <\frac{2\varepsilon
}{\delta}\left\vert x\right\vert $ so $T$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Exploit linearity:
$$L(\lim_{h\to0}a+h)=L(a)+L(\lim_{h\to0}h)=L(a)+\lim_{h\to0}L(h)=\lim_{h\to0}L(a+h)$$
*(In case it is a net!)*

Comment: The reason is: Topological and linear structure are compatible. Linear maps respect linear structure. So if it respects topological structure at one point then it will respect topological structure at any point. *(Try to figure it out where - all these aspects had been used!)*